# Sistema de posts - Dicas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Olá, estou querendo criar um sistema de posts para meu site e tenho uma ideia inicial de como fazer, bem básica.

No básico, eu teria um  que vai enviar o texto de um `<textarea>` para o banco de dados, junto com o autor, data, etc..

No textarea eu notei que é possível o usuário colocar tags html (`<div>`, `<p>`..) então eu vou utilizar o htmlentities do php para evitar que o usuário utilize tais tags e acabem danificando o layout do site (é normal isso?).

Com isso, eu gostaria de saber como devo implementar opções tais como deixar texto em negrito, colocar imagem, uma url, etc.. Gostaria apenas de umas dicas de como implementar isso...

Esse da url tem alguns sites que no post ele mostra uma prévia do site e tals..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você pode usar plugins que "montam" um editor para você. Recomendo o CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/), tome cuidado ao tratar o valor que o textarea do CKEditor vai retornar, porque ele permite editar um post visualmente mas retorna um HTML. Há vários outros também, como, [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) e [Froala](https://www.froala.com/).